# How to merge selected members of sub-lists, that are functions, into one list in R without the for() loop?

Tags: r, list

I’m new to R so please bear with me.
I have a list of lazy loaded data frames like this:

```
dataPath <- "C:\\R_data"
dataFramesByYear <-
  lapply(
    list.files(dataPath, "*dataFrame.[2][0-9][0-9][0-9].feather"),
    function(fileName) {
      lazyDataFeather(fileName)
    })
```

I end up with a structure like this in dataFramesByYear (where data() is a function that either loads a file or returns previously loaded data and isLoaded is a Boolean):

```
list(list(data = data(), isLoaded))
```

I would like to combine several of these by-year data frames into one. I know I can do something like this and use rbindlist():

```
framesList <- list(dataFramesByYear[[1]]$data(), dataFramesByYear[[2]]$data(), dataFramesByYear[[3]]$data())
combinedData <- 
  as.data.frame(
    rbindlist(
      framesList, 
      use.names = TRUE))
```

Sometimes the year indexes are supplied as a vector, however this does not work (RStudio reports "index out of bounds"):

```
yearIndexes <- 1:3
framesList <- dataFramesByYear[[yearIndexes]]$data()
```

Is there a one-liner way to define the framesList without using a for() loop?

Comment: What do you mean by "several"? Is there a rule for the data frame choice?

Comment: @amarchin Several in this case means between two and all available data frames. The indexes are supplied as a list through a function parameter and they are consecutive but do not necessarily start at 1.

Comment: Without a reproducible example is not easy... Anyway to avoid the "index out of bounds" error for the last command you need to do this: `framesList <- dataFramesByYear[yearIndexes]$data()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to how you are feeding the list with the index vector: you have to use `[` instead of `[[` as in the example below

```
l <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
ix <- c(1, 3, 4)
l[ix]
```

> [[1]] [1] 1
>
> [[2]] [1] 3
>
> [[3]] [1] 4

So you need to execute `framesList <- dataFramesByYear[yearIndexes]$data()` instead of `framesList <- dataFramesByYear[[yearIndexes]]$data()`

Comment: That almost worked except for the $data() part. framesList <- dataFramesByYear[yearIndexes]$data() returns an error: attempt to apply non-function
However, your answer pointed me in the right direction. With the addition of lapply() the correct result is achieved:

yearIndexes <- 1:3 ;
framesList <- dataFramesByYear[unlist(yearIndexes)] ;
combinedData <- 
  as.data.frame(
    rbindlist(
      lapply(
        framesList, 
        function(listData) { listData$data() }), 
      use.names = TRUE))